# Numbering only the last equation in a set of equations

Tags: equations, numbering

I have the following long equation:

```
\begin{align}
  F\bigl(\mathbf{u};z \;\vert\; Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr)
    &= \prob\bigl\{ Z(\textbf{u}) \leq z,Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr\} \\
    &= \dfrac{\prob \bigl\{Z(\mathbf{u}) \leq z,Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr\}}
             {\prob \bigl\{Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr\}} \\
    &= \dfrac{F(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}';z,z')}
             {F(\mathbf{u}';z')}
\end{align}
```

It looks like this for now:

[image]

But, I would like to number once i.e. something like this:

[image]

I have many questions that are connected to each other so have to mention them throughout my writing..

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those parts of the equation you don't want to number, add `\nonumber`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\prob}{Prob}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  F\bigl(\mathbf{u};z \mid Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr)
    &= \prob\bigl\{ Z(\mathbf{u}) \leq z \mid Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr\} \nonumber \\
    &= \dfrac{\prob \bigl\{Z(\mathbf{u}) \leq z,Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr\}}
             {\prob \bigl\{Z(\mathbf{u}') \leq z'\bigr\}} \nonumber \\
    &= \dfrac{F(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}';z,z')}
             {F(\mathbf{u}';z')}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```